# appending or insertion at last in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to insert a value at the end of a doubly linked list , I get successful in inserting the value at head or first node but the second value is not getting inserted

The issue here is while entering the second value

```
class d_list
{
private:

    struct node
    {
        double data;
        node *next;
        node *previous;
    };

    node *first;
    node *last ;
public:
    d_list(void)
    {
        first = nullptr;
        last = nullptr;
    };
    void append(double);

};

void d_list::append(double num)
{
    node *ptr;
    node *toinsert;
    if(!first)
    {
        first = new node;
        first->previous= nullptr;
        first->data = num;
        last= new node;
        first->next= last->previous;
        last->previous = first->next;
        last->next= nullptr;

    }
    else
    {
        if(last->next == nullptr)
        {
            ptr = new node;
            ptr->next =last->previous;
            ptr->data=num;
            last->previous = ptr->next  ;
        }


        last->next= nullptr;
    }

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    d_list aa;
    cout<<"going to append first"<<endl;
    aa.append(44);
    cout<<"going to append second"<<endl;
    aa.append(50.5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the symptom?  What did you learn when your ran your program in the debugger?

Comment: Please stop writing ",C++" at the end of all your titles. We know it's C++, because it has the `c++` tag.

Comment: a few time when I did changings it showed the access violation error , if made a tweet and it got eradicated then I see no vlaue in the next node data of head , also no value at the previous of last node

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I write it for search engine, I feel this title of my question is also been searched at Google  , so that next time anyone Google it get answer without using space of SO

Comment: @sparkling_spark: Stack Overflow already puts the first tag in the title, and presents metadata properly. I wouldn't worry about search engines; SO is _very_ good at being indexed, as I'm sure you've noticed. Writing tags in titles in some personal, unconventional, unindexed, inconsistent style just confuses that system and makes searching _worse_.

Comment: @sparkling_spark Hint: `last` should _always_ end up pointing to the newly appended node. Look at your control paths.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin   which line ? i just completed simple linked list and saw a diagram of wikipedia of doubly linked list and then wrote above code , what i am doing is assigning the new pointer(ptr) to previous of last and then the already previous of last with the next of new ponter(ptr)

Comment: Adding tags to your title is not necessary.  Please concentrate on making your title describe the crux of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your code:

- Your `node` next and previous members are never initialized anywhere and as a result are undefined when used. Either add a constructor to `node` or ensure they are initialized after allocation.
- The addition of a node to an empty list is not correct. `first->next` is left undefined and why are you creating two nodes, both first and last? In a list with one element then `first == last`. The setting of next/previous in first/last doesn't make any sense either.
- In a well formed double-linked list then `last->next` should always be null, as should `first->previous`.
- The addition of a node into a non-empty list is also incorrect.
- While you don't show it in the example, you'll eventually need a destructor as well as a copy operator and copy constructor (the rule of three). At the moment you are leaking memory and if you try to delete nodes you'll likely result in a double-free and crash.

I would suggest taking a step back from the code for a bit to ensure you properly understand the concepts behind a doubly-linked list. Draw out a list on paper with next/prev arrows and see how they need to be changed when adding nodes to an empty/non-empty list as well as how to delete and move nodes around. Once you figure out how next/prev should be set then translating that into code should be relatively straight forward.

Edit to answer comment:
To add a new node you can technically add it anywhere but it is usually added at the end (at least from what I've seen). See the other answers for a complete and correct code for adding new nodes in an empty and non-empty list.

Comment: i highly appreciate the experts which talk about the core concepts and stimulate thinking

Comment: I figured out this , that when ever I create first node (by new ) I point out its previous to null , and point its next to last , now here is a thing , should I assign last to create a new node? I am not understanding the entry of 2nd item to the list .

Answer (score 2):

```
...
if(last->next == nullptr)
{
  ptr = new node;
  ptr->next =last->previous; // <- is not correct
  ptr->data=num;
  last->previous = ptr->next  ; // <- does not do anything useful
  ...
```

You don't append your new node to the list.

```
...
if(!last->next)
{
  ptr = new node;
  ptr->previous=last->previous;
  ptr->next =last;
  ptr->data=num;
  last->previous = ptr  ;
  ...
```

should be better. By the way: delete the allocated memory in a destructor!

Comment: why this please ? if(!last->next)

Comment: and there is one more thing please , it do append data at the end but in debugger it does not show data in the next of first

Comment: Yes, you made the same mistake there. first->next should be last and last->previous should be first for the first element insertion. !last->next is the same as last->next == 0. Note that you should initialize first.next/previous with 0. Create a constructor for that.

Comment: didnt I had it ? d_list(void)
    {
        first = nullptr;
        last = nullptr;
    };

Comment: You implemented a constructor for list. You did non implement a constructor for node.

Answer (score 2):

I would write your double linked list in following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class d_list
    {
    private:

        struct node
        {
            double data;
            node *next;
            node *previous;
        };

        node *first;
        // node *last ; no need for bidirectional list
    public:
        d_list(void)
        {
            first = nullptr;
            //last = nullptr;
        };
        void append(double);

    };

    void d_list::append(double num)
    {
        node *ptr = new node;
        ptr->data = num;
        node *toinsert;
        if(!first)
        {
            first = ptr;
            first->previous=first->next=first;
        }
        else
        {
            if(first->next == first)
            {
                ptr->next = ptr->previous = first;
                first->next = first->previous = ptr;
            }
            else{
                node *last = first->previous;
                ptr->next = first;
                ptr->previous = last;
                last->next = ptr;
                first->previous = ptr;
            }
        }
    }


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        d_list aa;
        cout<<"going to append first"<<endl;
        aa.append(44);
        cout<<"going to append second"<<endl;
        aa.append(50.5);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I need bi directional link list , isn't bi directional is a doubly liked list ?

Comment: i think this will need iterations if you want to insert at the last , cant we avoid it by having birectional list ?

Comment: I treat double linked list same as bi directional link list. there is no need to iterate to insert at the last, just use last=first->previous.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you inserted the declarations `node *ptr;` and  `node *toinsert;` if you don't use them? Also it should be obvious that if you insert a single node at the end, then only one new element should be created(and you call new twice if first is null).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
class d_list 
{


private:
      struct node
      {
         double data;
         node *next;
         node *previous;
     };
      node *first;
     node *last ;

 public:
     d_list(void)
     {
         first = nullptr;
         last = nullptr;
     };

     void append(double);
  }; 

 void d_list::append(double num)
 {
     node *ptr;
     node *toinsert;
     if(!first)
     {
         first = last = new node;
         first->previous= nullptr;
         first->next = nullptr;
         first->data = num;
     }
     else
     {
             ptr = new node;
             ptr->next =last->previous;
             ptr->data=num;
             last->previous = ptr->next  ;
     }
  }


 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
     d_list aa;
     cout<<"going to append first"<<endl;
     aa.append(44);
     cout<<"going to append second"<<endl;
     aa.append(50.5);
      return 0;
 }
```